# Mapstruct doesn't generate BeanMapperImpl.java when used with Intellij and Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, mapstruct

Previously I used Mapstruct with Eclipse and it works fine (Gradle was used with command "eclipse" to generate the Eclipse project files and the build was done by Eclipse itself). After migration to Intellij, Mapstruct doesn't generate BeanMapperImpl.java any more. My build.gradle is as below:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.9'
}

...

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'
    ...
}

subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final'
        apt 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final
        ...
    }
}
```

And Intellij's build is delegated to Gradle.

Comment: And was Gradle used before as well? If the IntelliJ delegates the build to IntelliJ it means that something is wrong with your Gradle setup.

Comment: @Filip Before Gradle was used with command "eclipse" to generate the Eclipse project files and the build was done by Eclipse itself.

Comment: But were you using some CI that was just running the gradle build? It seems to me that it has something to do with gradle. Have you tried increasing the version of the apt plugin?

Comment: @Filip Do you mean tools like Jenkins? No, I'm not using anything like that. I also upgrade net.ltgt.apt to 0.15, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IntelliJ version, you can just dump the net.ltgt.apt plugin and make mapstruct-processor a `compileOnly` dependency.

With older versions of IntelliJ, results may vary.

IN gradle, the java files may get generated next to `.class` files. While not clean you can filter them out during packaging like this:

```
jar {
    exclude('**/*.java')
}
```

Changing the target folder may also be possible...

Comment: Would you give an example? I simply remove the plugin and change the dependencies to: 
compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final'
compile 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final'
but no files are generated in .apt_generated directory.

Comment: different plugins use different folder structures. IntelliJ and gradle may use different folder structures. There is no contract where those files go. I think for me generated mapstruct java files just go into the build/classes folder with gradle, but into out/production/classes/generated folder with intelliJ. The .class files also go into classes.